# How to set Default value of table field to 0.00?

Tags: mysql, database, default

I have created a table named "salary_mst" in MySql database.
Table fields are

```
id -> auto increment
name -> varchar(50)
salary -> double
```

Now if someone don't insert value in salary, it should store default 0.00
How can I do that ?

Comment: If you had typed this title in google you could have found many answers. :-)

Comment: I found this page as the first result on google, so his "laziness" has just helped me :-)  SO beats documentation and manuals for little details like this!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `table`  ADD COLUMN `column` FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
```

Answer (score 15):

```
create table salary_mst (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(50),
    salary double not null default 0
);
```

To test:

```
insert into salary_mst (name) values ('foo');
select * from salary_mst;
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | salary |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | foo  |      0 |
+----+------+--------+
```